# Docker executor in Gitlab CI gets passed wrong url to Git repo

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a Gitlab server setup on an internal server, on a domain like `http://gitlab.example.com`. I have also registered both a runner using the `shell executor` as well as a runner using the `docker executor`, both on the same machine as the Gitlab server.

I have this very basic .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
runtest:
    script:
        - npm install
```

When I run this via the runner using `shell executor`, everything works just fine. The repo is checked out, and it runs a npm install.

However, when I run this via the runner configured as a `docker executor`. I get the following error:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.4.2 (6d06f2e)
  on Test runner (fe943c63)
Using Docker executor with image node:6 ...
Using docker image 
sha256:81e132bdd65c157234d121b7c1743360c0d0d60f9bb6322f75ffa87c8f561ad8 for 
predefined container...
Pulling docker image node:6 ...
Using docker image node:6 
ID=sha256:3d258692b9fa0ba9568a891e1c702eee61d43e35286bec1b6fb0964700ca1dea for 
build container...
Running on runner-fe943c63-project-5-concurrent-0 via gitlab...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/internal/boilerplate'...
fatal: repository 'http://example.com/internal/boilerplate.git/' not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

The issue being, that my Gitlab server is on a subdomain called `gitlab.example.com` and the runner tries to checkout the code from `http://example.com`. It is as if the docker executor gets passed the wrong server url, and therefore cant correctly check out the Git repo.

I cant figure out why there is a difference between the two runners, and where to perhaps configure Gitlab to use the correct path to the git repo for all runners?

Edit: here is the output from running `ps aux | grep gitlab`

```
git        373  1.5  9.5 657036 385916 ?       Sl   13:08   0:04 unicorn worker[0] -D -E production -c /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/unicorn.rb /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config.ru
gitlab-+   389  0.0  0.7 1121208 30444 ?       Ss   13:08   0:00 postgres: gitlab gitlabhq_production [local] idle
gitlab-+   406  0.0  0.5 1115624 23832 ?       Ss   13:09   0:00 postgres: gitlab gitlabhq_production [local] idle
gitlab-+   407  0.0  0.5 1116772 24104 ?       Ss   13:09   0:00 postgres: gitlab gitlabhq_production [local] idle
gitlab-+   409  0.0  0.6 1116852 24784 ?       Ss   13:09   0:00 postgres: gitlab gitlabhq_production [local] idle
gitlab-+   412  0.0  0.6 1117364 24644 ?       Ss   13:09   0:00 postgres: gitlab gitlabhq_production [local] idle
root       615  0.0  0.0   4252  1120 ?        Ss   Aug14   0:00 runsvdir -P /opt/gitlab/service log: ....................................................................................................................................................................................................$
root       674  0.0  0.0   4100   644 ?        Ss   Aug14   0:00 runsv gitlab-monitor
root       680  0.0  0.0   4100   676 ?        Ss   Aug14   0:00 runsv gitlab-workhorse
root       689  0.0  0.0   4244  1156 ?        S    Aug14   0:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/prometheus
root       707  0.0  0.0   4244  1236 ?        S    Aug14   0:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/gitaly
root       708  0.0  0.0   4244  1240 ?        S    Aug14   0:01 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse
root       709  0.0  0.0   4244  1068 ?        S    Aug14   0:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/unicorn
root       710  0.0  0.0   4244  1228 ?        S    Aug14   0:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/sidekiq
root       711  0.0  0.0   4244  1064 ?        S    Aug14   0:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/logrotate
root       712  0.0  0.0   4244   696 ?        S    Aug14   0:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/nginx
root       713  0.0  0.0   4244  1216 ?        S    Aug14   0:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/postgresql
root       714  0.0  0.0   4244  1156 ?        S    Aug14   0:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/redis-exporter
root       715  0.0  0.0   4244  1128 ?        S    Aug14   0:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/postgres-exporter
root       716  0.0  0.0   4244  1228 ?        S    Aug14   0:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-monitor
root       717  0.0  0.0   4244  1244 ?        S    Aug14   0:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/node-exporter
root       739  0.0  0.0   4244  1060 ?        S    Aug14   0:00 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/redis
gitlab-+  1546  0.0  0.5 1115740 21052 ?       Ss   13:14   0:00 postgres: gitlab gitlabhq_production [local] idle
gitlab-+  1547  0.0  0.4 1114536 18512 ?       Ss   13:14   0:00 postgres: gitlab gitlabhq_production [local] idle
gitlab-+  1548  0.0  0.4 1114884 19224 ?       Ss   13:14   0:00 postgres: gitlab gitlabhq_production [local] idle
srv       1565  0.0  0.0  12740  2248 pts/0    S+   13:14   0:00 grep gitlab
root     27235  0.1  0.4  56260 20132 ?        Ssl  12:30   0:03 /usr/bin/gitlab-ci-multi-runner run --working-directory /home/gitlab-runner --config /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml --service gitlab-runner --syslog --user gitlab-runner
git      27266  0.0  0.3 130316 14280 ?        Ssl  12:30   0:00 /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/gitaly /var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/config.toml
git      27271  0.1  0.7 311376 32044 ?        Ssl  12:30   0:04 /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/gitlab-mon web -c /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-monitor/gitlab-monitor.yml
git      27274  0.0  0.3 228128 15244 ?        Ssl  12:30   0:01 /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/gitlab-workhorse -listenNetwork unix -listenUmask 0 -listenAddr /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/socket -authBackend http://localhost:8080 -authSocket /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket -docum$
root     27282  0.0  0.0   4340  1576 ?        Ss   12:30   0:00 /bin/sh /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/gitlab-logrotate-wrapper
root     27288  0.0  0.1  42056  5532 ?        Ss   12:30   0:00 nginx: master process /opt/gitlab/embedded/sbin/nginx -p /var/opt/gitlab/nginx
gitlab-+ 27289  0.0  0.1  46688  7700 ?        S    12:30   0:00 nginx: worker process
gitlab-+ 27290  0.0  0.0  42260  3088 ?        S    12:30   0:00 nginx: cache manager process
gitlab-+ 27293  0.0  0.3 119656 14768 ?        Ssl  12:30   0:01 /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/node_exporter -web.listen-address=localhost:9100 -collector.textfile.directory=/var/opt/gitlab/node-exporter/textfile_collector
gitlab-+ 27298  0.0  0.2 116904 11336 ?        Ssl  12:30   0:00 /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/postgres_exporter -web.listen-address=localhost:9187 -extend.query-path=/var/opt/gitlab/postgres-exporter/queries.yaml
gitlab-+ 27305  0.0  1.2 1103620 52328 ?       Ss   12:30   0:00 /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/postgres -D /var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/data
gitlab-+ 27307  0.0  0.7 1103736 29220 ?       Ss   12:30   0:00 postgres: checkpointer process
gitlab-+ 27308  0.0  0.2 1103620 10880 ?       Ss   12:30   0:00 postgres: writer process
gitlab-+ 27309  0.0  0.5 1103620 20664 ?       Ss   12:30   0:00 postgres: wal writer process
gitlab-+ 27310  0.0  0.1 1104192 6284 ?        Ss   12:30   0:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process
gitlab-+ 27311  0.0  0.0  31808  3952 ?        Ss   12:30   0:00 postgres: stats collector process
gitlab-+ 27314  0.2  1.4 370924 59220 ?        Ssl  12:30   0:05 /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/prometheus -web.listen-address=localhost:9090 -storage.local.path=/var/opt/gitlab/prometheus/data -storage.local.chunk-encoding-version=2 -storage.local.target-heap-size=109384826 -config.file=/var/opt/gitlab$
gitlab-+ 27323  0.4  0.1  41556  5648 ?        Ssl  12:30   0:12 /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:0
gitlab-+ 27328  0.0  0.2  39396 10968 ?        Ssl  12:30   0:00 /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/redis_exporter -web.listen-address=localhost:9121 -redis.addr=unix:///var/opt/gitlab/redis/redis.socket
git      27333  1.7  9.7 714348 396880 ?       Ssl  12:30   0:46 sidekiq 5.0.0 gitlab-rails [0 of 25 busy]
git      27357  0.0  0.0  20124  2956 ?        Ss   12:30   0:00 /bin/bash /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/gitlab-unicorn-wrapper
git      27376  0.5  7.8 577152 320180 ?       Sl   12:30   0:14 unicorn master -D -E production -c /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/unicorn.rb /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config.ru
gitlab-+ 27382  0.0  0.4 1115236 18844 ?       Ss   12:30   0:01 postgres: gitlab-psql postgres [local] idle
git      27485  0.4  9.9 687964 405976 ?       Sl   12:31   0:10 unicorn worker[1] -D -E production -c /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/etc/unicorn.rb /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config.ru
gitlab-+ 27517  0.0  0.9 1130316 39788 ?       Ss   12:31   0:00 postgres: gitlab gitlabhq_production [local] idle
gitlab-+ 30455  0.0  0.6 1117852 26280 ?       Ss   12:50   0:00 postgres: gitlab gitlabhq_production [local] idle
```

Comment: use `ps aux | grep gitlab` and check if they both have the same command line params

Comment: I am not quite sure how I can use the output from that to see that (I am not an linux expert)

Comment: Post output from both the server in your question and we will try and help you out

Comment: Its all on the same server. The runners are just two different configurations. That is why I find it odd, that the url Gitlab CI tries to checkout from, is wrong when using the docker executor :)

Comment: Past your config then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by network settings on the runner. The network bridge that was automatically setup between the host and the docker executor was 'outside' our local network. So the docker container was unable to see the url `gitlab.example.com`.

I solved it by adding

```
network_mode = "host"
```

To the config.toml for the docker runner.

That way the runner shares the same network as the host, and thus have the access it needs.